# How to align a form in the center of the page?

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment, center

With the following code, it shows me that the form is centered on its right side which isn't what I'm going for. I struggle to align the form in the center of the page from the center of the form. I added the HTML and CSS so you can see what it looks like. I hope someone can help resolve this problem :')

```css
.contacter {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.contacter h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}


/*formulaire -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.formulaire {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5%;
  padding-top: 0;
  width: 90%;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
}

.form {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

#message {
  height: 200px;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #9BA7C0;
  border-color: transparent;
  width: 175px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

div.frm {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="boite-1">
    <section class="contacter">
      <h1>CONTACTER L'ETUDE</h1>
      <div class="formulaire">
        <form class="frm">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="frm-col">
              <input type="text" class="form" name="nom" id="nom" placeholder="Nom*">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="frm-col">
              <input type="text" class="form" name="societe" id="societe" placeholder="Société">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="frm-col">
              <input type="text" class="form" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="Adresse mail*">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="frm-col">
              <input type="text" class="form" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Téléphone*">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="frm-col">
              <textarea class="form" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="7" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="sbmt">
              <input type="submit" value="Envoyer la demande" class="btn">
              <span class="demande envoyée"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

```
.frm-col {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your css file replace the .contacter with this below

```
 .contacter {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0px;

  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This will solve your issue

for more info on flex : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score -1):

```
.formulaire{
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 90%; // try using a fixed with if it is still not working
}
```

or

```
.frm-col{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: You have edited your question after raz-ezra posted his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73135833/17235431) and included his answer in yours. Please don't do that

Comment: No. I forgot to add this part. I just noticed it.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong too, it should be `display: flex;` without quotes

Comment: Why don't you spend some time reviewing your answer before posting it? Why don't you edit your mistake now?

Comment: Edited it. Too late now!

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.